# Display Action Sheet - Change Signature

Tags: android, xamarin

Please can you help me with this error? I need to add Dialog Action Sheet into my application for android but there is error and I dont know how I can solved it.

[image: Code Here]

Visual Studio give me only this help

[image: Change Signature]

Is there anybody who can help me? Thank you

Comment: You need to add {} after declaration. Unless it is marked as `abstract` a method should have a body even if empty. So remove *;* and add {}

Comment: where? sorry I dont understand you :-(

Comment: change the line to below and try: public `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> DisplayActionSheet(string title, string cancel, string destruction, params string[] buttons){}`

Comment: now I have this error "MainActivity.DisplayActionSheet(string, string, string, params string[])': not all code paths return a value"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? That's basic C# syntax error. Signature of method is `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> DisplayActionSheet(string title, string cancel, string destruction, params string[] buttons){}`. So it is expecting return value in the form of fulfilled `Task<string>`. I would suggest you to get familiar with C#. Meanwhile either return a value or change the signature to `void`